# If I know the name of a function, is it possible to get its parameters?

Tags: reflection, dart, dart-mirrors

Dart code:

```dart
void hello(String name) {
    print(name);
}

main() {
    var funcName = "hello";
    // how to get the parameter `String name`?
}
```

Using the function name as a string, `"hello"`, is it possible to get the parameter `String name` of the real function `hello` ?

Comment: When you passing something this is calling `parameter`. Eg. `func(param1)`. When you get this `parameters` in `function body` this called already not `parameter` but an `argument`. `Where`, `how` and `what` (`parameters` or `arguments`) you want get?

Comment: I want the `parameter` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [mirrors](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_mirrors.html) to do that.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

void hello(String name) {
    print(name);
}

main() {
  var funcName = "hello";

  // get the top level functions in the current library
  Map<Symbol, MethodMirror> functions = 
      currentMirrorSystem().isolate.rootLibrary.functions;
  MethodMirror func = functions[const Symbol(funcName)];

  // once function is found : get parameters
  List<ParameterMirror> params = func.parameters;
  for (ParameterMirror param in params) {
    String type = MirrorSystem.getName(param.type.simpleName);
    String name = MirrorSystem.getName(param.simpleName);
    //....
    print("$type $name");
  }
}
```

Comment: I got `String <TODO:unnamed>`?

Answer (score 2):

You get this information through reflection (which it is not yet fully completed):

```Dart
library hello_library;

import 'dart:mirrors';

void main() {
  var mirrors =  currentMirrorSystem();
  const libraryName = 'hello_library';
  var libraries = mirrors.findLibrary(const Symbol(libraryName));
  var length = libraries.length;
  if(length == 0) {
    print('Library not found');
  } else if(length > 1) {
    print('Found more than one library');
  } else {
    var method = getStaticMethodInfo(libraries.first, const Symbol('hello'));
    var parameters = getMethodParameters(method);
    if(parameters != null) {
      for(ParameterMirror parameter in parameters) {
        print('name: ${parameter.simpleName}:, type: ${parameter.type.simpleName}');
      }
    }
  }
}

MethodMirror getStaticMethodInfo(LibraryMirror library, Symbol methodName) {
  if(library == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return library.functions[methodName];
}

List<ParameterMirror> getMethodParameters(MethodMirror method) {
  if(method == null) {
    return null;
  }

  return method.parameters;
}

void hello(String name) {
    print(name);
}
```